# android, how to cancel current request in retrofit2/rxjava-android

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am new in retrofit/rxjava-android

Someone told me that, it is best practice if I will cancel the request if the call is not yet finished and the user leaves the activity page.

I am having problem where/how to cancel it.

Here's my code, it is working properly.

```
Observable<List<MyObject>> call;
public void getStaticMessages() {
    call = restInterface.loginURL();
    call.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Observer<List<MyObject>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d("LOGGER", "error");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<MyObject> myObjects) {
            Log.d("LOGGER", "succcess");
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the best practice is to create subscription/disposable when `onStart()` method of activity/fragment is called and unsubscribe /dispose when `onStop` called.

You can create one disposable `Disposable disposable = call.subscribeOn` and dispose it via `disposable.dispose()` or use [CompositeDisposable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/disposables/CompositeDisposable.html).

I used the same approach with CompositeDisposable in one of my previous pet projects - [link](https://github.com/ValeriiVolkov/Weather/blob/master/app/src/main/java/weather/vvolkov/view/list/CityListPresenter.java)